# Custom Linux Desktop Environment on Electron

Tags: kde

Is it possible to create Desktop Environment like KDE or GNOME using Electron framework? How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

For sure you won't be able to run KDE or Gnome from a Javascript environnement.
But, some Javascript desktop projects exists (like the one you can see on FreeboxOS).

Take a look to OS.js for example : https://demo.os-js.org/

Best regards and good luck in integration.